# File Upload handler

Tags: java, jsp, file-upload

This is a code of File Upload Handler 
This is working Fine on my server but after uploading file it only displays File Uploaded successfully
but i also want to display the name of file which is uploaded

```
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.List;
 import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
 import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
 import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
 import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

public class FileUploadHandler extends HttpServlet {
private final String UPLOAD_DIRECTORY = "C:/uploads";

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    //process only if its multipart content
    if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)){
        try {
            List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(
                                     new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);

            for(FileItem item : multiparts){
                if(!item.isFormField()){
                    String name = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                    item.write( new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + name));
                }
            }

  //File uploaded successfully

           request.setAttribute("message", "File Uploaded Successfully");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
           request.setAttribute("message", "File Upload Failed due to " + ex);
        }          

    }else{
        request.setAttribute("message",
                             "Sorry this Servlet only handles file upload request");
    }

    request.getRequestDispatcher("/done.jsp").forward(request, response);

}

}
```

Comment: is the file actually uploaded? and you are only missing the filename? in that case it might be an encoding issue with the arabic characters not being displayed in your browser

Answer (score 1):

Store `item.getName()` in a variable for later use.  Since you are using a loop, you'll have to keep track of multiple filenames if there are any.

```
   String fileNames = ""; //to keep list of filenames
   for(FileItem item : multiparts){
            if(!item.isFormField()){
                fileNames += item.getName() + "; "; //add filename to string
                String name = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                item.write( new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + name));
            }
        }
    .....
    .....
    request.setAttribute("message", "File(s) Uploaded Successfully: " + fileNames );
```

Answer (score 0):

this code may help you!

```
private static String getFileName(Part part) {
    for (String cd : part.getHeader("content-disposition").split(";")) {
        if (cd.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
            String filename = cd.substring(cd.indexOf('=') + 1).trim().replace("\"", "");
            return filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('/') + 1).substring(filename.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1); // MSIE fix.
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```