# Why is the name of the file I upload null? jsp/servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, file-upload

Ι upload a photo using the following servlet and it works. But when I print the photo's name in a jsp page it is null. I need it so as to save it in my database. Any ideas?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

public class FileUploadHandler extends HttpServlet {
    private final String UPLOAD_DIRECTORY = "C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 6.0\\webapps\\ismgroup9\\fileUpload";

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)){
        try {
            List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);

            for(FileItem item : multiparts){
                if(!item.isFormField()){
                    String name = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                    item.write( new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + name));
                    request.setAttribute("photoname", name);
                }
            }

           request.setAttribute("message", "File Uploaded Successfully");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
           request.setAttribute("message", "File Upload Failed due to " + ex);
        }

    }else{
        request.setAttribute("message", "Sorry this Servlet only handles file upload request");
    }

    request.getRequestDispatcher("/uploadfileController.jsp").forward(request, response);

}
```

}

Comment: How do you print it in JSP? Also `request.setAttribute("photoname", name);` probably should be placed outside of `for` loop to avoid overwriting value from earlier iteration as shown in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22850370/1393766).

Comment: `code` <%
String photoname = (String)request.getAttribute("photoName");

%>
<%= photoname %> 
That's how I print it. I try what you suggested but it still prints null

Comment: Since this information is quite important you should [edit] your question and place it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment it seems that you used

```
request.getAttribute("photoName");
//                         ^here is the problem
```

but your attribute was set with name `photoname`.

```
request.setAttribute("photoname", name);
```

Java is case-sensitive so `photoname` and `photoName` are not equal names. Always double check your variable names.

Comment: I whould never have seen that! Thank you very much!